# Matlab sparse and dense matrix concatenation mismatch

Tags: matlab, concatenation, sparse-matrix

I have the following problem in MATLAB.

`d` is a dense matrix dimensions c,t

`f` is a dense matrix dimensions u,p

`p` is a cell array (dimension p) in which each cell contains a logical sparse matrix of indexes of dimensions c,t

I want to execute the following instruction:

```
for r=1:u
    f(r,:) = mean(mean(d(p{:})))
end
```

I noted that if p contains full logical matrices the command works, but since they are sparse it isn't working. It gives me the error: "matrix dimensions must agree".

I know that the : syntax concatenates the content of an array, and I know that I can circumvent it with another for cycle. 
Does anyone knows how to execute this command without an additional for cycle?

Comment: Can you make your notation more clear? For instance "`p` is a cell array (dimension `p`)" is very confusing...